# TFS 2012 Express permission inheritance - not all permissions inherited from group

Tags: tfs, permissions, system-administration

Can anybody explain why not all of the Team Foundation Server 2012 Express permissions are inherited? Is it expected TFS behavior?

I'd expect that a user added to Project Collection Administrators group (the most powerful one) has all the permissions inherited, while actually he doesn't have:

[image: tfs permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.90).aspx

The "not set" simply means that the permission is inherited for the given user from its parent group. They have just not been explicitly set at this node.

Comment: accepted, although it seems a bit weird that some permissions are "inherited allow" and some "not set"